# Spring Boot Hikari properties override programmatically

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, hikaricp

I have two datasources in my Spring Boot app and therefore I cannot use the standard datasource properites. One of them is defined like below:

```
vertica:
  datasource:
    jdbc-url: jdbc:vertica://${DR_HOST}:${DR_PORT}/${DR_DB_NAME}
    username: ${DR_USER}
    password: ${DR_PASSWORD}
    driver-class-name: com.vertica.jdbc.Driver
    hikari:
      connectionTimeout: 30000
      idleTimeout: 10000
      maxLifetime: 10000
      keepaliveTime: 5000
      maximumPoolSize: 20
      minimumIdle: 5
      #poolName: vertica-db-pool
      #username: ${DB_USER}
      #password: ${DB_PASSWORD}
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
      format_sql: true
      show-sql: true
      naming:
        physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
      naming-strategy: org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.VerticaDialect
```

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("vertica.datasource")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "verticaEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "verticaTransactionManager",
        basePackages = { "com.yyy.vertica" }
)
public class MyDataSourceConfig extends HikariConfig {
    public final static String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = "vertica";
    public final static String PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = "com.xxx.entity";

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public HikariDataSource verticaDataSource() {
        return new HikariDataSource(this);
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean verticaEntityManagerFactory(
            final HikariDataSource verticaDataSource) {

        return new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean() {{
            setDataSource(verticaDataSource);
            setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
            setPersistenceUnitName(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
            setPackagesToScan(PACKAGES_TO_SCAN);

            Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
            jpaProperties.put("hibernate.ddl-auto", env.getProperty("vertica.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto"));
            jpaProperties.put("hibernate.show-sql", env.getProperty("vertica.jpa.hibernate.show-sql"));
            jpaProperties.put("hibernate.format_sql", env.getProperty("vertica.jpa.hibernate.format_sql"));
            jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("vertica.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect"));

            setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);

            afterPropertiesSet();;
        }};
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager verticaTransactionManager(EntityManagerFactory verticaEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(verticaEntityManagerFactory);
    }
```

The Hikari properties defined in yaml file above are not taken into account (possibly due to `extends HikariConfig`). The requirement is to use the default Hikari properties and override the ones defined above. Please suggest how this can be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not extend `HikariConfig`.

Use the default constructor of `HikariConfig()` to take the default configuration properties of Hikari and then override what you need according to your properties file as you have already done for your `jpa` properties.

```
@Bean
public HikariDataSource verticaDataSource() {
 HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
        
hikariConfig.setConnectionTimeout(env.getProperty("vertica.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout", Long.class)); 
  
hikariConfig.setIdleTimeout(env.getProperty("vertica.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout", Long.class)); 

hikariConfig.setMaxLifetime(env.getProperty("vertica.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime", Long.class)); 

hikariConfig.setKeepaliveTime(env.getProperty("vertica.datasource.hikari.keepaliveTime", Long.class));

hikariConfig.setMaximumPoolSize​(env.getProperty("vertica.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize", Integer.class));

hikariConfig.setMinimumIdle​(env.getProperty("vertica.datasource.hikari.minimumIdle", Integer.class));

return new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);

}
```

Comment: This means that all the default properties are gone and only the ones I define will be in effect? I am out right now but I think I tried it earlier in the day. Is it not possible to use the defaults and override only the ones we want?

Comment: @curious_brain According to documentation the default constructor of hikariconfig which I have used here provides the default configuration proprties. Then you override only those that you need

Comment: It worked as expected except that I have to set datasource properties (like ```jdbc-url```, ```driver-class-name```, ```username```, ```password```) also to hikariConfig. This means that ```@ConfigurationProperties("vertica.datasource")``` becomes ineffective!!!

Comment: @curious_brain the `@ConfigurationProperties` did not play any role in the code even from before. For it to play you should had a field in the class where those properties should have been injected into.

Comment: It did have an effect. If you see my original code, the database address and credentials were read from the properties file. Am I missing something?